# C++ code hangs, even in GDB

Tags: c++, gdb, valgrind

C++ code with around 5k lines hangs randomly - in linux. My code deals with transmitting and reception of packets through RAW socket.  The code just stops at a point randomly without any response - not even [ctrl+c] proves handy :: every time after hang I used to kill the process.
I tried GDB and result was same it hanged - ctrl+c produced a SIGTERM error message .
On using valgrind the code hanged similarly .

How to debug this issue? Is it any kind of system error?

Comment: What was the backtrace (`bt`) in GDB after you sent the signal?

Comment: blocking read of packets perhaps

Comment: @OliCharlesworth : As i said the code hangs off ::ctrl+c doesnt help , so i killed the running program in gdb  . (bt) shows "NO stack ".

Comment: @Deepthought : Blocking read of pakets means ? Is it the ethernet issue ? i use pcap in my code.

Comment: The part of code which receives the packet ... It may be the case that the read socket is blocking(non-returning untill operation finsihed) call. The socket may not be responding since it has not read anything. So your code also waits indefinitely. Ctrl-C doesn't help  as The invoking thread may be in an UNITERUPTIBLE_SLEEP. Post the part of code which does read and write from socket may be people can give better advice

Answer (score 0):

Using strace command , it was clear that the hang was due to futex_wait_private issue. Socket read was pushed into deadlock scenario. On increasing the select timeout value - the issue could be resolved.